# I can not send program to ESP8266 module

Tags: lua, iot, esp8266

Yesterday I got ESP8266, NodeMCU v2.0. I have a problem with module. I Use Esplorer IDE. I have simple code in LUA language.

```
gpio.mode(4,gpio.OUTPUT)
gpio.write(4,gpio.LOW)
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.config("Livebox-C408","7255E6262488CC90482CE6F264")
print(wifi.sta.getip())
```

When I send program to ESP8266, Esplorer shows below error.

```
stdin:2: '=' expected near 'a'
stdin:2: ')' expected (to close '(' at line 1) near 'TATION'
```

Sometimes(~10%) I can send above program to ESP8266 without problem. In my opinion, ESP8266 is damaged. What do you think about my problem?

Anticipating your questions, login and password to my home wi-fi are correct.

Comment: Is this done i.e. did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- There's no such thing as NodeMCU v2.0. What you probably mean is v2 or 1.0. v1 was revision 0.9. See [my comparison](http://frightanic.com/iot/comparison-of-esp8266-nodemcu-development-boards/) for details.
- Your code is doomed to "fail" because it doesn't consider the fact that `wifi.sta.config()` is asynchronous i.e. it won't block until an IP address was assigned. `print(wifi.sta.getip())` will eventually print `nil`. We have an [example for a better boot sequence in the docs](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/upload/#initlua).
- Your device most likely is not damaged.
- In the ESPlorer settings tinker with the turbo and dumb modes. I have "Turbo Mode" on and "Dumb Mode" off. Futhermore, set your baud rate to 115'200.
- In case you haven't done so already I strongly suggest to [upgrade your firmware to a recent version](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/flash/#upgrading-firmware). See [here](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/build/) how to build it.